# How to Join tables with multiple uniques ordered by timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

i've got a peculiar problem

I have 2 tables, table A and table B.

A has materialid and a bunch of other fields
B has materialid, intnumber, timestamp

I need do a join so that the result set is:

Each line from A gets a line from B, with INTnumber Desc and Timestamp ASC, but they have to be unique

So, if i have 4 records in A, and 53 records in B, the result set would be 4 records, and each result would be unique to each other.

Example

A has:

```
materialid
mat1
mat1
mat2
```

B has:

```
materialid, intnumber, timestamp
mat1,1,50
mat1,1,60
mat1,1,70
mat2,1,65
mat2,1,70
mat3,3,50
```

Resultset would be:

```
mat1,1,50
mat1,1,60
mat2,1,65
```

Any hints?

to give a 'real' feeling on this, table 'b' is material in the warehouse and date of entry, table 'a' is material request - we need to associate the request to the position of the material in the warehouse, but we always need to give out the 'oldest' staying material (hence the order by timestamp)

Thanks

Comment: can you add column names?? have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Imagine that table A stores one row with `mat1`, not two. What output needed in this case?

Comment: if table A stores one row with a single mat1, the output should be mat1,1,50; basically only table a is important... 

to give a 'real' feeling on this, table 'b' is material in the warehouse and date of entry, table 'a' is material request - we need to associate the request to the position of the material in the warehouse, but we always need to give out the 'oldest' staying material (hence the order by timestamp)

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign unique numbers to the rows of the 2 tables for each `materialid`, so you can use them to join the tables properly:

```
WITH 
  cteA AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY materialid) rn FROM A),
  cteB AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY materialid ORDER BY timestamp) rn FROM B)
SELECT b.materialid, b.intnumber, b.timestamp
FROM cteB b INNER JOIN cteA a
ON (b.materialid, b.rn) = (a.materialid, a.rn)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fec459178ca859e2ac2dda18a8a37429).
Results:

| materialid | intnumber | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mat1 | 1 | 50 |
| mat1 | 1 | 60 |
| mat2 | 1 | 65 |